Would like to know how these two functions work and if they are correct
/**
     * @dev Internal Function to convert bytes32 to hex string without 0x
     * @param _bytes32 the byte array to convert to string
     * @return hex string from the byte 32 array
     */
    function _bytes32ToHexString(
        bytes32 _bytes32
    ) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _string = new bytes(64);
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
            _string[i * 2] = HEXCHARS[uint8(_bytes32[i] >> 4)];
            _string[1 + i * 2] = HEXCHARS[uint8(_bytes32[i] & 0x0f)];
        }
        return string(_string);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Internal Function to convert bytes array to hex string without 0x
     * @param _bytes the byte array to convert to string
     * @return hex string from the bytes array
     */
    function _bytesToHexString(
        bytes memory _bytes
    ) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _string = new bytes(_bytes.length * 2);
        uint256 len = _bytes.length;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            _string[i * 2] = HEXCHARS[uint8(_bytes[i] >> 4)];
            _string[1 + i * 2] = HEXCHARS[uint8(_bytes[i] & 0x0f)];
        }
        return string(_string);
    }


To be clear, it's the same function. One it's generalised to work with any bytes length and the other one is for a size of 32 bytes. You can check this:
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/hexadecimal/converting-tofrom-binary#:~:text=Converting%20between%20hex%20and%20binary,represented%20by%20two%20hexadecimal%20digits.
It's works as any base change, nothing special on here. Could you be more specific on what's exactly you are looking for?
